# Accessing data from an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following Json Object

```
[
  { "key": "age", "value": 81 },
  { "key": "name", "value": "Luis" }
]
```

I am trying to find the most optimal way to recover this data.

const name = ??????;

What's the best way to extract the "value" of the 'name' key using Javascript? I know one of the ways would be to iterate until I find the value, but I figured there is a more fancy way, perhaps using filter?

Luis

Comment: `find` is probably your best bet, actually-- `filter` will iterate the entire array, looking for multiple matches, whereas `find` will stop once it finds a match, saving you superfluous computation.

Comment: Fancy doesn't mean better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you need the object that has `key` as `name`

You can get use of `find` method

```
let array = [
  { "key": "age", "value": 81 },
  { "key": "name", "value": "Luis" }
]

let your_obj = array.find(element=>element.key === 'name')

console.log(your_obj) // this will give you the object you need
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give results with key `name`

```
names = [
  { "key": "age", "value": 81 },
  { "key": "name", "value": "Luis" }
]
result = names.filter(name => name.key === 'name')
```